# How do I use route name in a url in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

php artisan route:list is as follows:

```
 | GET|HEAD  | posts/{post}/edit | posts.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\PostController@edit        | web
```

how do I use the route name 'posts.edit' so that it appears in the blade.php file?

Currently I use the HTML Laravel package and wrote `{{ Html::linkRoute('posts.edit', 'Edit', array($post->id), array('class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-block')) }}`

but I would like to use plain html in the blade templating engine without HTML Laravel package. Is there a way to utilize the route name 'posts.edit' in the blade file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You usually use it with [`route()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-route) helper:

```
<a href="{{ route('posts.edit', ['id' => $post->id]) }}">Link</a>
```

In this case you'll not need to use Laravel Collective HTML package.